# How to start to solve set expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove next set expression

$${x \in (A \cap B) \setminus C \to x \notin A \oplus B \oplus C}$$

I have no idea how to start to solve it

Could you please give me at least a clue how to start?

Comment: Apply the definitions: $x \in (A \cap B) \setminus C$ iif $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First work out what the lefthand side tells you about $x$: $x\in A\cap B$, so $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, but $x\notin C$. Now you know that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$; is $x\in A\oplus B$, or not? Once you have the answer to that, combine it with the knowledge that $x\notin C$ to finish up, bearing in mind that $x\notin A\oplus B\oplus C=(A\oplus B)\oplus C$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Logically I understood, like x∈A⊕B is true, but because of x∉C it causes that  x∉A⊕B⊕C. Question is - if there is a way to prove it mathematically? or such kind of expressions we need to prove exactly this way?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko: This approach is often the simplest. (And it is mathematical; it just isn’t presented as a chain of equations or implications. Many mathematical arguments aren’t.) However, what you’re asked to prove is equivalent to showing that $$\big((A\cap B)\setminus C\big)\cap(A\oplus B\oplus C)=\varnothing\;;$$ this **could** be done as a long computation, but it would be very ugly.